# Virtual Copy Constructor and Clone method

Tags: c++, clone

I was on "virtual copy constructor" topic in my book. The paragraph says

> Constructors cannot be virtual, and so, technically, no such thing exists as a virtual copy
> constructor. Nonetheless, at times, your program desperately needs to be able to pass in a
> pointer to a base object and have a copy of the correct derived object that is created. A
> common solution to this problem is to create a Clone() method in the base class and to
> make that be virtual. The Clone() method creates a new object copy of the current class
> and returns that object.

And then book gave the following code (I have removed some part of it which was not necessary related to my doubt).

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class Mammal
{
 public:
  Mammal() {}
  Mammal (const Mammal & rhs);
  virtual void Speak() const 
   { 
    cout << "Mammal speak!\n"; 
   }
  
  virtual Mammal* Clone() 
   { 
    return new Mammal(*this); 
   }
};
 
 Mammal::Mammal (const Mammal & rhs)
 {
  cout << "Mammal Copy Constructor\n";
 }

 class Dog : public Mammal
{
 public:
  Dog() {}
  Dog (const Dog & rhs);
  void Speak()const 
   { 
    cout << "Woof!\n"; 
   }
 
  virtual Mammal* Clone() 
   { 
    return new Dog(*this); 
   }
};

 Dog::Dog(const Dog & rhs): Mammal(rhs)
 {
  cout << "Dog copy constructor...\n";
 }

 enum ANIMALS { MAMMAL, DOG};
 const int NumAnimalTypes = 2;
 int main()
{
 Mammal* theArray[NumAnimalTypes];
 Mammal* ptr;
 int choice, i;
 for ( i = 0; i<NumAnimalTypes; i++)
  {
    cout << "(1)dog (2)Mammal: ";
    cin >> choice;
  
    switch (choice)
     {
      case DOG: ptr = new Dog;
             break;
 
      default: ptr = new Mammal;
            break;
     }
    theArray[i] = ptr;
  }

 Mammal* OtherArray[NumAnimalTypes];
  for (i=0;i<NumAnimalTypes;i++)
   {
    theArray[i]->Speak();
    OtherArray[i] = theArray[i]->Clone();
   }
  for (i=0;i<NumAnimalTypes;i++)
   OtherArray[i]->Speak();
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(1)dog (2)Mammal: 1
(1)dog (2)Mammal: 2
Woof!
Mammal Copy Constructor
Dog copy constructor...
Mammal speak!
Mammal Copy Constructor
Woof!
Mammal speak!
```

I didn't get the exact intuition behind the use of `clone()` method. Meaning I commented out the `clone()` function part in above code and changed the sixth last line to `OtherArray[i] = theArray[i];` and I guess that still do what actual code intended to do.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 class Mammal
{
 public:
  Mammal() {}
  Mammal (const Mammal & rhs);
  virtual void Speak() const 
   { 
    cout << "Mammal speak!\n"; 
   }
  
 /* virtual Mammal* Clone() 
   { 
    return new Mammal(*this); 
   } */
};
 
 Mammal::Mammal (const Mammal & rhs)
 {
  cout << "Mammal Copy Constructor\n";
 }

 class Dog : public Mammal
{
 public:
  Dog() {}
  Dog (const Dog & rhs);
  void Speak()const 
   { 
    cout << "Woof!\n"; 
   }
 
 /* virtual Mammal* Clone() 
   { 
    return new Dog(*this); 
   } */
};

 Dog::Dog(const Dog & rhs): Mammal(rhs)
 {
  cout << "Dog copy constructor...\n";
 }

 enum ANIMALS { MAMMAL, DOG};
 const int NumAnimalTypes = 2;
 int main()
{
 Mammal* theArray[NumAnimalTypes];
 Mammal* ptr;
 int choice, i;
 for ( i = 0; i<NumAnimalTypes; i++)
  {
    cout << "(1)dog (2)Mammal: ";
    cin >> choice;
  
    switch (choice)
     {
      case DOG: ptr = new Dog;
             break;
 
      default: ptr = new Mammal;
            break;
     }
    theArray[i] = ptr;
  }

 Mammal* OtherArray[NumAnimalTypes];
  for (i=0;i<NumAnimalTypes;i++)
   {
    theArray[i]->Speak();
    OtherArray[i] = theArray[i];
   }
  for (i=0;i<NumAnimalTypes;i++)
 OtherArray[i]->Speak();
 return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
(1)dog (2)Mammal: 1
(1)dog (2)Mammal: 2
Woof!
Mammal speak!
Woof!
Mammal speak!
```

Can someone please explain me why and where we need to use `clone()` method and it's connection with virtual copy constructor. Thanks.

Comment: Your modified version does not copy the objects, only pointers to them.

Comment: Don't leave out the virtual destructor (for other reasons). I also note that your objects don't have any data to copy, so they don't really fit the use case of needing a clone.

Comment: The point of the example is not the animal sounds but the copying, and it is clear from the output that your version doesn't copy anything.